# alternatekeysql

Tags: sql

I'm just learning how to create a data warehouse
i want to create categoryalternatekey
I came up with a solution like this
Mix the first three letters of the category, the first three letters of the name, and the first three letters of the category type
for example categoryname oilengine '3120-14113-15912'
Is this the right way?

is this the right way?

Comment: only if the combination is unique,

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach. It's hard to tell whether it  will help you, though. Keys like this are usually chosen to make your database lookups, or maybe your report presentations, faster and easier to use.

Comment: You need to explain why you are creating this key, what it is going to be used for, etc in order for anyone to be able to help you